# Multiple Views for one ViewModel on a CreateCar Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a wizard with 5 steps, where in each step I get information from the user for his car sale. First it's the operation type (Sale, Rent), second is the Category (Car, Truck, Boat), third is the details of the item (Make, Model, Version), four is the extras and five is the member address.

Each step list of options is build using @Ajax.ActionLink and send the result to a specific DIV in the following master page (Operations -> Category -> Ad -> Extras -> Member -> Create):

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.CreateAdViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Ad.Create(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createAdForm" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="operation">
         @{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Ad.CreateAdOperation()); }
    </div>
    <div id="category"></div>
    <div id="ad"></div>
    <div id="extras"></div>
    <div id="member"></div>

   <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

This master page has the "master" ViewModel "CreateAdViewModel" that will receive all the information from all the steps, creating all the "inputs" to be sent to the CreateAd Action.

What I have now is a ViewModel for each step:

```
public class CreateAdOperationViewModel
{
    // Operation Fields
}

public class CreateAdCategoryViewModel
{
    // Category Fields
}

public class CreateAdViewModel
{
    // Common Ad Fields
}

public class CreateAdCarViewModel : CreateAdViewModel
{
    // Car View Model Fields
}
```

The main problem is to know if this solution makes sense because has far has I know, each View should have his own ViewModel, but I need to submit a master ViewModel based on diferent Views, each one with its own ViewModel.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can share ViewModels across Views, on the basis that these Views need access to the same data. If the shared data is only partial, and not the entire view, you can have separate ViewModels (one ViewModel per View) with a shared "context" property that contains the shared data.

Here is an example article that shows how to do that: http://blog.bitdiff.com/2012/05/sharing-common-view-model-data-in.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I have some dificulties to map the article with my issue :(